# Return true for first instance of a number in a different column

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a column that goes like this:-

1

1

2

2

3

4

5

5

5

In another column I need to display TRUE for the first occurrence of a number ONLY, else FALSE. So:-

1  TRUE

1  FALSE

2  TRUE

2  FALSE

3  TRUE

4  TRUE

5  TRUE

5  FALSE

5  FALSE

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

B1: `=(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1)`
B2: `=(COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A2)=1)`

etc. (you can just drag and drop the formula)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following formula. This assumes that your numbers are from C4 onwards. This is the formula in D4

```
=COUNTIF($C$1:$C3,C4)=0
```

Comment: Hi there. My numbers are in C2 to C4064 and I need the results in the corresponding cells in column D. So D2 to D4064

Comment: Well, just drag the formula down. It should work. You have a sorted column, right?

Comment: Yes actually it does. Excellent. Thanks Amit!

Comment: If the numbers are grouped as shown then this formula in D2 copied down would be sufficient `=C2<>C1`

Comment: @barryhoudini That's true. Overlooked that!